# Extjs4 + Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, extjs4.2

Is it possible to integrate rest services using  tomacat and exjs4 ?
Below is my code without rest service .
Please , if any one having sample code for rest services using tomcat , provide me ,

View :

```
   Ext.define('ValidationGUI.view.DynamicPanelView', {
            extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            alias : 'widget.dynamicPanelView',
            id:'DB1',


            border : 30,
            items : [
                  {
                xtype : 'checkbox',
                fieldLabel : "",
                inputValue : 1,
                boxLabel   : 'DB1',
                id:'checkBox1'
                  },

            {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'DB',
                name:'DB'

            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Username',
                name:'Username'

            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Password',
                name:'Password'

            },{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Hostname',
                name:'Hostname'

            },{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Port',
                name:'Port'

            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Service',
                name:'Service'

            }]


});

controller:
Ext.define('ValidationGUI.controller.MainController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models : [ 'DBConfigurationData' ],
    stores : [ 'DBConfigurationStore' ],
    views : [ 'DBConfigurationView','DynamicPanelView','Dummy' ],

    init : function() {
        this.dapnel=null;
        this.count = 1;
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel' : {
                render : this.onPanelRendered
            },
            'dbconfiguration button#Add' :{
                click:this.createPanel
 },
            'dbconfiguration button#Delete':{
                click:this.deletePanel
        }
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered : function() {
    //  debugger;
      //this.getAllValues('');
    },

    createPanel : function() {
       this.count++;
        this.dpanel = new Ext.Panel({
                    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
                    //title : 'DB'+this.count,
                    id:'DB'+this.count,
                    border : 30,
                    items : [{
                         xtype      : 'checkbox',
                             fieldLabel : "",
                             inputValue : this.count,
                             boxLabel   : 'DB'+this.count,
                             id:'checkBox'+this.count
                                },

                             {
                                xtype : 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel : 'DB',
                                dataIndex : 'DB'

                            }, {
                                xtype : 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel : 'Username',
                                dataIndex : 'Username'
                            }, {
                                xtype : 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel : 'Password',
                                dataIndex : 'Password'
                            }, {
                                xtype : 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel : 'Port',
                                dataIndex : 'Port'
                            }, {
                                xtype : 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel : 'Service',
                                dataIndex : 'Service'
                            }]
                });
                Ext.getCmp('vBoxPanelId').add(this.dpanel);
                Ext.getCmp('vBoxPanelId').add(this.dpanel).doLayout();
            //  Ext.getCmp(this.count);
                //Ext.getCmp('test').getBottomToolbar().add(myCheckboxGroup);
                //Ext.getCmp('test').getBottomToolbar().doLayout();


    },
    deletePanel : function() {
            //  alert("inside delete panel");
                for (var i = 1; i <= this.count; i++) {
                    //var id='checkBox'+i;
                    //alert(id);

                    if (Ext.getCmp('checkBox'+i)!=undefined && Ext.getCmp('checkBox'+i).checked){
                        //alert(Ext.getCmp('checkBox'+i).checked);

                        Ext.getCmp('vBoxPanelId').remove(Ext.getCmp('DB'+i),true);
                        //Ext.getCmp('DB2').remove(this.dpanel).doLayout();
                    }

            }

    }

});
Model :
Ext.define('ValidationGUI.model.DBConfigurationData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name:'DB', type: 'string'}, 
             {name: 'Username', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'Password', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'Hostname', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'Port', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'Service', type: 'string'}]
});

Store:
Ext.define('ValidationGUI.store.DBConfigurationStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     constructor: function(cfg) {
                   var me = this;
                   cfg = cfg || {};
                   me.callParent([Ext.apply({
                       autoLoad: true,
                       model: 'ValidationGUI.model.DBConfigurationData',
                       storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
                       proxy: {
                           type: 'ajax',
                           url: 'data/dbdetails.json',
                           reader: {
                               type: 'json',
                               root: 'data'
                           }
                       }
                   }, cfg)]);
               }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can achieve this easily using Apache rest webservices, Try using "Jersey api's". (ref : http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)
In Extjs we can call those services by ajax calls 
eg:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',
   success: function(response, opts) {
      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      console.dir(obj);
   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
   }
});
```